# yum-updatesd problem

Tags: centos, yum

I am trying to setup yum-updatesd to send email notification when there are updates available to the packages on my system.  However, I am not receiving any notifications even though there are updates available (as seen in yum check-update)

I have verified that the yum-updatesd service is running.

This is my /etc/yum/yum-updatesd.conf:

```
[main]
# how often to check for new updates (in seconds)
run_interval = 3600
# how often to allow checking on request (in seconds)
updaterefresh = 600

# how to send notifications (valid: dbus, email, syslog)
emit_via = email
email_to = me@myemail.com
email_from = yum-updatesd@mydomain.com

# should we listen via dbus to give out update information/check for
# new updates
dbus_listener = yes

# automatically install updates
do_update = no
# automatically download updates
do_download = no
# automatically download deps of updates
do_download_deps = no
```

Comment: Is `yum-updatesd` pulling down new metadata, and just not telling you, or is it failing to work at all? What if you run it from the command line with `--no-fork`, `--oneshot`, and `--debug`?

Comment: I assume it is pulling down the new metadata but not telling me.

Here is the output: 
Introspect error: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files

Going to exec: ['/usr/libexec/yum-updatesd-helper', '--check', '--email', '--email-from=yum-updatesd@master.myserver.com', '--email-to=me@myserver.com', '--smtp-server=localhost:25', '--sendmail', '--debug']

the rest of it looks correct and shows the updates available from yum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with my spam folder and not yum-updatesd.  The configuration above is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

is sendmail running? If you type "echo hi | mail -s test you@you.com" do you get the message?